# Htaccess conflict SEO Url friendly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The code below seems to conflict with index.php

How Would i go about allowing index.php? :) > http://www.domain.com/

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ live.php?content=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

note: i still want it to rewrite the url to /$1

all help is grateful i will obviously thank the solution.

if you have a solution for this without affecting the current structure feel free to post below.

Answer (score 0):

Better to add a `RewriteCond` to avoid rewriting for existing files/directories:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ live.php?content=$1 [L,QSA]
```